# Oracle SQL query - Display max only?

Tags: sql, group-by

I have the code below in an oracle SQL query. This code finds the username of a member and how many times they voted each year. How can I modify this so that it only shows the user/s that have voted the highest number of times?

```
SELECT username, count(username), extract(year from voteDate) as vote_year,
max(count(*)) over (partition by extract(year from voteDate)) as Max_votes
FROM rankingInfo NATURAL JOIN memberinfo
GROUP BY username, extract(year from voteDate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your query correctly, your `max_votes` returns the max votes you want and your `count(username)` returns the votes for each user.  If so, you can put the results in a subquery and then just add `WHERE` criteria:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
   SELECT username, count(username) votes, extract(year from voteDate) as vote_year,
       max(count(*)) over (partition by extract(year from voteDate)) as Max_votes
   FROM rankingInfo NATURAL JOIN memberinfo
   GROUP BY username, extract(year from voteDate)
) T
WHERE votes = max_votes
```